# ImageIO and URLs

Tags: java, url, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

Having some annoying issues with loading images into a BufferedImage (image in the example) with the use of ImageIO.read, due to there being spaces in the Image name;

```
image = ImageIO.read(new File(getClass().getResource("/Pictures/H ello.jpg").getPath()));
```

If I rename the url(?) "/Pictures/H ello.jpg" to "/Pictures/Hello.jpg" and the source image to Hello.jpg it works just fine.

I've tried replacing the spaces with %20 as found on other questions and also a replace char of ' ' to '+'. So what am I doing wrong? Would encoding solve my problem and how would I do that?

Thanks,

Comment: So do you get some error ? Or Exception ?

Comment: "javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!" was what I was getting, has been solved however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following possibly works.

```
image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Pictures/H ello.jpg"));
```

Comment: THis also fixes the issue. Thanks a ton, should I use this or the afforementioned solution?

Comment: If the application is delivered as jar/war/... then File will not function, as that would be reading inside a zip format. So this is without wrong extra turn.

Answer (score 1):

```
java.net.URL path = getClass().getResource("/Pictures/H ello.jpg");
ImageIO.read(new File(path.toURI()));
```

Does this work? I think it should. URL will decode space as %20 and `File` constructor should process it properly as an `URI`

Comment: Yes that seems to have fixed it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great. I'm glad that I've been of help.

Answer (score 1):

if you want this way, then you need to decode the url:

```
image = ImageIO.read(new File(URLDecoder.decode(getClass().getResource("/Pictures/H ello.jpg").getPath(), "UTF-8")));
```

but, if I need to work with resources, I'd use overloaded method ImageIO.read(URL) or ImageIO.read(InputStream) :

```
image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Pictures/H ello.jpg"));
image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Pictures/H ello.jpg"));
```

see [apidoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html)